# How to search a certain folder or disk and only get the results for that folder or disk

Tags: files, search, 21.10

I searched a disk for a certain file name and I got the results for the whole pc.  I made sure the file manager window was inside the disk (CANON_DC) like this and searched ike.[image]

The file manager window was in CANON_DC. As you can see by some of the directory names, like Documents/Jeshua.. and Pictues/fun photos... All these are from the home folder. I got files for the whole pc; not just the disk.  How can I narrow this down?

Comment: Is it OK with a command line solution, or must it be a GUI solution?

Comment: @sudodus - would be nice to have both!

Comment: Catfish is a really nice GUI solution, and it pretty easy to integrate with the various linux graphical file managers.

Comment: Could that be because you are using tracker? Normal behaviour for Nautilus also would be to search starting from the current directory

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### The command line way

You can use `find` to find a file in a specified directory tree, for example

```
$ find ~ -name "*bashrc*"
/home/sudodus/.bashrc

$ find /etc -name "*bashrc*"
/etc/bash.bashrc
/etc/skel/.bashrc
```

`find` is a very powerful tool. It takes time to learn everything, but this is a good start. See `man find`, read tutorials via the internet and ask here at AskUbuntu in order to learn more about it.

### The GUI way

It seems the built-in search tool in Files alias `nautilus` will search the whole computer. But there are many Linux tools, that can be installed in Ubuntu. You find them easily via the internet, e.g. via [this link](https://www.fossmint.com/file-searching-tools-for-linux/)

Some of them let you specify the search path or 'filter', for example FSearch, ULauncher, Catfish.

Recoll is an advanced tool that can also search for content in the files (corresponding to `grep` on the command line).

Comment: You can take the command-line solution to the next level by feeding the search results from `find` to file manager [`nnn`](https://github.com/jarun/nnn) so you can navigate through the results and analyze them visually - `find ~ -name "*bashrc*" -print0 | nnn -H`

Comment: @Arun, yes, it is possible and some users will find it useful. You are welcome to write an answer where you show how to do it, for example with a demo with some screenshots.

Comment: I have shared the command which is an extension of your example. That should be enough to try it out.

Comment: @Arun, OK. Anyway, I did look at your github page and the animation :-)